# Are the different senses of "stale" really cognate?

Tags: etymology, middle-english, homonyms

This is a question about etymology.

I have read all the freely available dictionary entries online, including etymoline, but they seem unclear at best if not downright contradictory. I do not have access to the OED so if anybody does it might be helpful to include in the answer what the OED has to say on this.

So Oxford Languages, via Google, suggests the common sense of "stale" came from Old French

> Middle English (describing beer in the sense ‘clear from long standing, strong’): probably from Anglo-Norman French and Old French, from estaler ‘to halt’; compare with the verb stall.

My first question is: Is there a corresponding word in vulgar Latin or Latin?

And the same source suggests that's the case for the "urinate" verbal sense which also shares the common ancestor *estaler*. But there is no explanation as to how that sense evolved from standing for too long.

Wiktionary seems to suggest these senses have different roots, with the more common adjectival form being:

> From Middle English stale, of uncertain etymology, but probably originally from Proto-Germanic *stāną (“to stand”): compare West Flemish stel in the same sense for ‘beer’ and ‘urine’.

There is no mention of a French source. For the verbal "urinate" sense:

> Noun from Middle English stale, from Anglo-Norman estal (“urine”), from Middle Dutch stal (“urine”). Cognate with Middle Low German stal (“horse urine; bowel movement”). Verb from Middle English stalen, from Old French estaler (“urinate”), related to Middle High German stallen (“to piss”).

Question #2, so they are not cognate? I'm confused. Or did two different words somehow converge in Middle English?

Comment: I don't think the Old French sense is related to standing for too long. A horse will normally stop when it needs to urinate. I suspect it originated as a euphemism, to avoid mentioning a disgusting bodily function.

Comment: It's OK to ask about etymologies of English words, but asking about the relation between French and Latin is probably off topic. Anyway, have you looked at this site which seems relevant https://www.etymonline.com/word/stale

Comment: _Stale_ falls in the residue for [ST- phonosemantics](https://websites.umich.edu/~jlawler/st.pdf), with no discernible semantic link to either of the two groups with notable coherence.